# finding word associations using natural language processing

Tags: python, nltk

Given words like "romantic" or "underground", I'd like to use python to go through a list of text data and retrieve entries that contain those words and associated words such as "girlfriend" or "hole-in-the-wall".

It's been suggested that I work with NLTK to do this, but I have no idea where to start and I know nothing about language processing or linguistics. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could at least try to attack your problem, especially because NLTK has an excellent introductory e-book on its web page. When you his some issue during that, you can post a more detailed question, with your code, that we can answer

Comment: *"I have no idea where to start"* - then you're in the wrong place, please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: try: https://github.com/alvations/Terminator/blob/master/terminator/association_measures.py

Comment: Hi, have you seen glove or word2vec?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us much to go on. But let's assume you have a paragraph of text. Here's one I just stole from a Yelp review:

> What a beautiful train station in the heart of New York City. I've grown up seeing memorable images of GCT on newspapers, in movies, and in magazines, so I was well aware of what the interior of the station looked like. However, it's still a gem. To stand in the centre of the main hall during rush hour is an interesting experience- commuters streaming vigorously around you, sunlight beaming in through the massive windows, announcements booming on the PA system. It's a true NY experience.

Okay, there are a bunch of words there. What kind of words do you want? Adjectives? Adverbs? NLTK will help you "tag" the words, so you can find all the ad-words: "beautiful", "memorable", "interesting", "massive", "true".

Now, what are you going to do with them? Maybe you can throw in some verbs and nouns, "beaming" sounds pretty good. But "announcements" isn't so interesting.

Regardless, you can build an associations database. This ad-word appears in a paragraph with these other words.

Maybe you can count the frequency of each word, over your total corpus. Maybe "restaurant" appears a lot, but "pesthole" is relatively rare. So you can filter that way? (Only keep "interesting" words.)

Or maybe you go the other way, and extract synonyms: if "romantic" and "girlfriend" appear together a lot, then call them "correlated words" and use them as part of your search engine?

We don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to make suggestions. But yes, NLTK can help you select certain subgroups of words, IF that's actually relevant.